# Designation menu on contribution page?

Tags: civicontribute

brand new user here looking for design options.  My user would like to have a drop-down menu on a generic contribution page so donations can be designated to 6 or so different possible choices by the donor.

I believe a more straight forward approach might be to have each designation be a separate campaign with it's on contribution page - but I need to look the drop-down menu option as well.  Is it possible to put a drop-down menu on a contribution page?  Is it possible to tie a selection made with the drop-down menu to the donation in a report somewhere?

Thanks in advance for all comments

Michael

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom drop-down "select" field to the contribution, then add the custom field to a profile on the contribution, optionally specifying it as required.

You'll then be able to search and report on your donations by custom field.